# systemd stops OrientDB immediately after it starts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: orientdb, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, orientdb2.2

I'm trying trying to make OrientDB run as a daemon (enabled on start) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  The problem is, systemd appears to call stop immediately after I tell it to start.  I have this systemd service file exactly as recommended in the OrientDB documentation:

```
[Unit]
Description=OrientDB Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/orientdb.sh start
ExecStop=$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/orientdb.sh stop
ExecStatus=$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/orientdb.sh status
```

orientdb.log:

`````
           .                                          
          .`        `                                 
          ,      `:.                                  
         `,`    ,:`                                   
         .,.   :,,                                    
         .,,  ,,,                                     
    .    .,.:::::  ````                                 :::::::::     :::::::::   
    ,`   .::,,,,::.,,,,,,`;;                      .:    ::::::::::    :::    :::  
    `,.  ::,,,,,,,:.,,.`  `                       .:    :::      :::  :::     ::: 
     ,,:,:,,,,,,,,::.   `        `         ``     .:    :::      :::  :::     ::: 
      ,,:.,,,,,,,,,: `::, ,,   ::,::`   : :,::`  ::::   :::      :::  :::    :::  
       ,:,,,,,,,,,,::,:   ,,  :.    :   ::    :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::     
        :,,,,,,,,,,:,::   ,,  :      :  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::::   
  `     :,,,,,,,,,,:,::,  ,, .::::::::  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     ::: 
  `,...,,:,,,,,,,,,: .:,. ,, ,,         :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     ::: 
    .,,,,::,,,,,,,:  `: , ,,  :     `   :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     ::: 
      ...,::,,,,::.. `:  .,,  :,    :   :     :   .:    :::::::::::   :::     ::: 
           ,::::,,,. `:   ,,   :::::    :     :   .:    :::::::::     ::::::::::  
           ,,:` `,,.                                  
          ,,,    .,`                                  
         ,,.     `,                                          GRAPH DATABASE  
       ``        `.                                                          
                 ``                                          orientdb.com
                 `                                    
pid file detected, killing process
`````

syslog:

```
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting OrientDB Server...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu orientdb.sh[17487]: Starting OrientDB server daemon...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of orientdb.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 999...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Session c5 of user orientdb.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Timers.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Paths.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Default.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Startup finished in 23ms.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 999.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu orientdb.sh[17508]: Stopping OrientDB server daemon...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user orientdb.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started OrientDB Server.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 999...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Stopped target Default.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[17497]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 17536 (kill).
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 999.
Jul 28 18:56:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of orientdb.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you follow the guide at this link (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Unix-Service.html) ?..

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I followed the documentation (see scripts above) and it doesn't work :).

Comment: ok, could you please open an issue on Github?.. thanks.

Comment: did you solved it? Same issue here on Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

As long as you wrap custom init scripts ([orientdb.sh](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/server/script/orientdb.sh)
, [server.sh](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/server/script/server.sh), [shutdown.sh](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/server/script/shutdown.sh)) in a systemd service unit, you will have strange and hard to debug issues.

Instead, you should read those scripts, understand how they launch OrientDB and reproduce only what is necessary in a service unit.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a user & group *orientdb* to the system and used below systemd script (assuming orientdb is installed in */opt/orientdb*):

```
[Unit]
Description=OrientDB Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=orientdb
Group=orientdb
ExecStart=/opt/orientdb/bin/server.sh
ExecStop=/opt/orientdb/bin/shutdown.sh
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the server and close the window, the server will be closed. Use it with NOHUP (server.sh) and if you close the window it will continue running.

I had the same problem, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with OpenSuse Leap 42.1 and OrientDB 2.2.7.
Roberto's answer solved it. See [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6511#issuecomment-240693030).